# Filter a column and populate the corresponding rows in a new Excel file using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dataframe, tkinter

I'm trying to filter a column which consist of a list of Product with its Description (it also contains a few product ID).

I'm using Tkinter as my GUI to give in 3 product IDs and get the IDs which look similar to it (in this case i provide 12345678s12 and get all IDS which look similar to it for eg. 34534534q23, 98765432y23 and so on)

[the data looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFfpP.jpg)

the script is below:

```
def clean():

    df['PO Item Description'] = df['PO Item Description'].astype(str).str.lower()  

    y =""
    M = entryx.get() # Entry one from tkinter
    N = entryx2.get() # Entry Two from tkinter
    O = entryx3.get() # Entry three from tkinter

    listx={'text1':[M,N,O]}

    for values in listx.values():
        if (listx["text1"][0]==listx["text1"][1]==listx["text1"][2]):
            text1 = listx['text1'][0]
            for i in range(0,len(text1)):

                r=re.match('[a-zA-Z]',text1[i])
                if r!=None:
                    y+='[a-zA-Z]'
                r=re.match('[0-9]',text1[i])            
                if r!=None:
                    y+='\d'       
                r=re.match('[.\,_/=&*()%^@$!#-]',text1[i])
                if r!=None: 
                    y+='\W'
                r=re.match('[ ]',text1[i])
                if r!=None:
                    y+='\s' 
        else:
            pass   

    ids = df['PO Item Description'].str.extract(r"({})".format(y),expand =False).dropna().tolist() #finds all items with similar Product ID

    resultxx= ''
    for product_IDs in zip(*[iter(ids)]):
        resultxx = pd.DataFrame(ids)
```

This code works, but is very clumsy as I'm new to Python.
Now my questions for the code are:

1. How do i make this code more efficient ?
2. How do i get the respective rows of which the columns have been filtered and populate these in a new excel file?

Please help me out.
Thank you in advance

Comment: `for frame in (f1,f2,f3):  frame.grid(row = 0,column = 0)` In here you are placing all on top of each other. About other issues, well, your question is too broad. Try to separate your question.

Comment: i separated it f1= tk.Frame(root) f1.grid(row=0,column=0), the problem persists.